# Unicode Decode Error

Tags: python, rdf, decode

Although I'm not a Python developer, I created some Python to convert some data to RDF.

I ran the code in Python 3.2 last week and it ran fine. Today however it is giving me the error

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):**

**File "C:\Users\Karen\Desktop\Linked Data new\RGC_v3.2.py", line 10, in <module>
    for row in reader: #look through each row in the csv file. row is an area where row[0] will be the first column, row[1] the second etc.
  File "C:\Python32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 754: character maps to <undefined>**
```

I don't know why this has suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 3):

You're assuming that the data is encoded in CP1252. Check [the usual suspects](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset) to determine the encoding used.